# Referenciar uma coluna de cores com base em outra

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho um dataset com várias colunas, porém uma específica coluna é referência para as cores do gráfico, como posso referenciar essa coluna no `scale_fill_manua` do ggplot de forma automática?

**Obs**. *A mesma cor pode ser usada em mais de uma referência.*

No caso manual seria somente criar `c("BIF"="#543005", "BRE"="#bf812d", ...)`, mas como são muitos dados haveria uma forma de automatizar isso?

**Meu dataset:**

```
> dput(dataset)
structure(list(INI = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 15.85, 20.95, 23.05, 
27.3, 32.2, 41.5, 41.75, 45.7, 50, 72.6, 74.3, 82.65, 104.45, 
105.2, 106.15, 107.05, 121.8, 123.2, 124.7, 126.7, 128.4, 136.4, 
139.7, 151.95, 154.35, 168.2, 172.2, 174.75, 177.35, 178.3, 179.85, 
235.2, 237.1, 246.45, 249, 254.75, 255.65, 256.55, 258.1, 258.55, 
259.85, 261.6, 261.85, 261.85, 268.7, 270.4, 273.45, 275.5, 277.6, 
294.9, 295.4, 308.9, 310.3, 312.3, 321.95, 327.85, 328.9, 330.3, 
332.15, 361.65, 368.15, 372.7, 380.7, 385.4, 386, 387.7, 389.2, 
392.2, 394.55, 395.7, 396.85, 398, 400, 400.6, 402, 402.9, 405.7, 
410.95, 414.7, 435.35, 436.35, 442.85, 443.5, 457.45, 457.75, 
465.35, 468.4, 474.5, 475.6, 478.65, 480.1, 483.7, 485.6, 498.8, 
501.05, 514.2, 522), FIM = c(0.9, 15.85, 27.3, 41.5, 20.95, 72.6, 
23.05, 41.75, 32.2, 82.65, 45.7, 50, 151.95, 104.45, 74.3, 105.2, 
121.8, 107.05, 106.15, 168.2, 123.2, 295.4, 124.7, 126.7, 128.4, 
136.4, 139.7, 246.45, 154.35, 254.75, 172.2, 174.75, 177.35, 
178.3, 179.85, 235.2, 237.1, 258.55, 249, 255.65, 258.1, 256.55, 
261.85, 261.6, 259.85, 261.85, 294.9, 268.7, 270.4, 327.85, 273.45, 
275.5, 277.6, 328.9, 310.3, 308.9, 312.3, 386, 321.95, 330.3, 
332.15, 361.65, 385.4, 368.15, 400, 372.7, 380.7, 389.2, 387.7, 
405.7, 395.7, 392.2, 394.55, 396.85, 398, 400.6, 402.9, 414.7, 
402, 410.95, 436.35, 457.45, 422.45, 435.35, 442.85, 443.5, 457.75, 
454.75, 465.35, 468.4, 514.2, 474.5, 475.6, 478.65, 480.1, 483.7, 
485.6, 498.8, 501.05, 522, 537.4, 526.7), UNIDADES = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("UND-0001", "UND-0012", "UND-0042", 
"UND-0075"), class = "factor"), REF = structure(c(8L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("BRE", "GAB", "GRA", "GRN", "HID", "RIO", 
"RIU", "SOL", "UNK"), class = "factor"), COLOR = c(26265L, 0L, 
0L, 4737279L, 215L, 215L, 4737279L, 215L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5014527L, 
4737279L, 215L, 4737279L, 4737279L, 5014527L, 215L, 4737279L, 
4737279L, 215L, 0L, 0L, 215L, 4737279L, 4737279L, 4737279L, 215L, 
0L, 4737279L, 4737279L, 215L, 4737279L, 4737279L, 4737279L, 4737279L, 
0L, 215L, 0L, 215L, 0L, 0L, 215L, 0L, 0L, 215L, 4737279L, 0L, 
0L, 215L, 0L, 4737279L, 0L, 4737279L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4737279L, 7602234L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4737279L, 4737279L, 0L, 215L, 0L, 0L, 4737279L, 
0L, 215L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7602234L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7602234L, 
4737279L, 0L, 0L, 4737279L, 8454016L, 5014527L, 0L, 4737279L, 
0L, 215L, 0L, 4737279L, 0L, 215L, 0L, 215L, 0L, 5014527L, 215L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -102L))
>
```

**Entrada:**

```
library("ggplot2")
library("broman")

dataset$COLOR = paste0("#",convert2hex(dataset$COLOR))
color = unique(dataset$COLOR)
aux = unique(dataset$REF)

ggplot(dataset, aes(UNIDADES, (INI + FIM)/2*-1, fill= REF)) +
  geom_tile(aes(height = (INI - FIM)*-1, width = 0.6), colour="black", size=0.1) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "UNIDADES", y = "TOTAL") +
  labs(fill = "REF")  +
  scale_fill_manual (values =dataset$COLOR)
```

**Saída:**

```
> color = unique(dataset$COLOR)
> aux = unique(dataset$REF)
> color
[1] "#006699" "#000000" "#4848ff" "#0000d7" "#4c83ff" "#74003a" "#80ff80"
> aux
[1] SOL HID GRN GRA UNK RIO BRE RIU GAB
Levels: BRE GAB GRA GRN HID RIO RIU SOL UNK
```

Comment: inclua o `dataset` na pergunta

Comment: Dataset incluso.

Comment: Perceba que no `df` disponibilizado não consta as variáveis `UNIDADES`, `INI` e `FIM`.

Comment: Talvez `color <- setNames(color, aux)`. E depois usar esse novo vetor em `scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: Obrigado pelo auxílio @Rui Barradas, porém posso ter cores iguais para diferentes referências.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente um dos problemas é a possibilidade de haver cores iguais para referências diferentes. A função `fun` abaixo resolve esse problema, criando um vetor de cores em que os nomes são valores únicos de `ref` e os valores de `cor` correspondentes.

```
fun <- function(ref, cor){
  cor <- as.character(cor)
  x <- unique(ref)
  i <- match(x, ref)
  setNames(cor[i], ref[i])
}
```

Para testar a função,cria-se um conjunto de dados `dataset2` com duas novas `REF`, de valores `BRC` e `BRD`. As cores são as de `BRE`.

```
dataset2 <- rbind(dataset, data.frame(REF = c("BRC", "BRD"), COLOR = rep("#bf812d", 2)))
dataset2$REF <- factor(as.character(dataset2$REF))
```

Agora atribuem-se as cores usando a função `fun`.

```
cores <- with(dataset2, fun(REF, COLOR))
```

E o resto do código é igual ao da [resposta de @Carlos Eduardo Lagosta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/462857/82237), só muda a base.

O gráfico será o seguinte, note a cor repetida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Código do link acima.

```
set.seed(99)
dataset2$UNIDADES <- LETTERS[1:nrow(dataset2)]
dataset2$var <- sample(1:100, nrow(dataset2))
dataset2$peso <- sample(1:100, nrow(dataset2))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dataset2, aes(reorder(UNIDADES, as.numeric(REF)), var)) +
  geom_tile(aes(height = peso, fill = REF), width = .6) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "UNIDADES", y = "TOTAL") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cores)
```

Answer (score 2):

Como apontado por @rui-barradas nos comentários, pode usar `setNames` para associar os nomes das cores com o código hexa, só precisa fazer isso como uma lista e garantir que os nomes estejam associados aos códigos corretos.

Também entendi pelo título que quer ordenar as barras pela ordem de REF. Para isso pode usar `reorder`.

Como não forneceu seu conjunto completo de dados, estou criando alguns dados mais simples.

```
# Dados
dataset <- structure(list(REF = structure(c(3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("BRE", "GAB",
"HID", "RIU", "UNK"), class = "factor"), COLOR = structure(c(3L,
2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L
), .Label = c("#01665e", "#4d4d4d", "#80cdc1", "#bf812d", "#f6e8c3"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-17L))
set.seed(99)
dataset$UNIDADES <- LETTERS[1:nrow(dataset)]
dataset$var <- sample(1:100, nrow(dataset))
dataset$peso <- sample(1:100, nrow(dataset))
#------------------------------------------------------------

library(ggplot2)

cores <- setNames(
  as.list(as.character(unique(dataset$COLOR))),
  unique(dataset$REF))

ggplot(dataset, aes(reorder(UNIDADES, as.numeric(REF)), var)) +
  geom_tile(aes(height = peso, fill = REF), width = .6) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(x = "UNIDADES", y = "TOTAL") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cores)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pelo ajuda @Carlos Eduardo Lagosta,porém em meu dataset pode haver cores iguais para diferentes referências assim a função setNames trava no mesmo problema para uma solução que havia pensado, concatenar REF e COLOR em um vetor.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta para incluir esse detalhe, junto com uma amostra *completa* dos seus dados. Sua pergunta deve ser auto suficiente; usuários não devem ler todos os comentários para saber o que precisa.

Comment: Sim, entendo. No momento que fiz a pegunta, repetição de cores não era uma possibilidade, porém como a base de dados é alimentada diariamente surgiu esse imprevisto. Farei a edição da pergunta para deixa-lá mais clara e completa, porém ela já está solucionada.